# FCM onBackgroundMessage not getting called in background flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been on this for a while now without a solution. I have been unable to handle notifications when app in background as `onBackgroundMessage` not getting called. What could be wrong?

```
Future<dynamic> _myBackgroundMessageHandler
    (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
  print("onBackground Message called");
  return PushNotificationService().showNotification(message);
}


class PushNotificationService{
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
  Future initialize(context) async{
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");
        fetchRideInfo(message['data']['orderId'], context, "onMessage");
      },
    onBackgroundMessage: Platform.isIOS ? null:_myBackgroundMessageHandler,

      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
        fetchRideInfo(message['data']['orderId'], context, "onResume");
      },
    );
  }

  Future showNotification(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'channel id',
      'channel name',
      'channel desc',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
    );

    var platformChannelSpecifics =
    new NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0,
      'new message arived',
      'i want ${message['data']}',
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: 'Default_Sound',
    );
  }
```

Comment: In Android or iOS?

Comment: just android bro

Answer (score 0):

In android/app/build.gradle add dependencies com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.3.0

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.3.0'
}
```

Then create a class with name Application.kt
NB: If you want to run something with FCM, then you have to register it too. In this case I handle background notification with flutter_local_notifications. If you have another one then register that one and don't forget to fix the imports.

```
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin
import io.flutter.view.FlutterMain
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService
import com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin 

   
class Application : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback {
    
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
        FlutterMain.startInitialization(this)
    }

    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
        if (!registry!!.hasPlugin("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging")) {
            FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry!!.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
        }
        if (!registry!!.hasPlugin("com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications")) {
            FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.registerWith(registry!!.registrarFor("com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin"));
        }
  }
    }
```

then register it in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
AndroidManifest.xml
     <application
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:name=".Application"
    
           >
.....
 </application>
```

Comment: I get this: Application must extend android.app.Application

Comment: not working bro. _myBackgroundMessageHandler not getting called